# How do i get the a macro to read the maximum value of my for, next loop from my worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this macro to simulate a dice being rolled for my math lessons. We are looking at predicted outcomes as against actual outcomes.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        Range("a" & i) = Int(Rnd() * (7 - 1) + 1)
    Next i  
End Sub
```

I want the macro to use a value from sheet 1 cell b2 instead of having to open and edit the macro when i want to change this number.

Comment: where you want to use Cell B2 value from sheet1? Please clarify?

Comment: your question is not clear enough. You want max value of col A or you want to use B2 value to calculate colA value?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CurrentValue As Long
    Dim MaxValue As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        CurrentValue = Int(Rnd() * (7 - 1) + 1)
        Range("a" & i) = CurrentValue
        If MaxValue < CurrentValue Then MaxValue = CurrentValue
    Next i  
    Range("B2") = MaxValue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just add another Variable and then read in the value of the Cell.

(you should probably add a check to see its a number or use DataValidation on the cell )

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iMax As Long 
    iMax = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("B2").Value

    For i = 1 To iMax
        Range("a" & i) = Int(Rnd() * (7 - 1) + 1)
    Next i  
End Sub
```